# nodes have a lot of cpu and mem usage on launching, and cause them be killed

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, ros-humble, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to launch some simple nodes on RaspberryPi 4B 4G, Ubuntu Server 22.04, which include a robot_state_publisher, a Lidar driver, a static_transform_publisher, and a wheels control node wrote by myself. They always die after just starting or running for a while. I found it from "top" when they first started (few seconds before they died or successfully run) that they used a lot of cpu and mem, tens of times the amount of normal, and can cause obvious lag at the terminal:

[image]

Sometimes it throw a std::bad_alloc and can leave a core dump file. When I try to use gdb to traceback the reason they crashed, I get something like this:

```
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=281472731705632, signo=signo@entry=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#1  0x0000ffff82baf254 in __pthread_kill_internal (signo=6, threadid=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:78
#2  0x0000ffff82b6a67c in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
#3  0x0000ffff82b57130 in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#4  0x0000ffff815b62dc in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x0000ffff815b2abc in ?? () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x0000ffff815b2b20 in std::terminate() () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x0000ffff815b2e04 in __cxa_throw () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x0000ffff815b43f8 in operator new(unsigned long) () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x0000ffff7a3222e8 in ?? () from /opt/ros/humble/lib/librmw_dds_common__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so
#10 0x0000ffff7a3228a4 in rmw_dds_common::msg::typesupport_fastrtps_cpp::cdr_deserialize(eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr&, rmw_dds_common::msg::NodeEntitiesInfo_<std::allocator<void> >&) () from /opt/ros/humble/lib/librmw_dds_common__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so
#11 0x0000ffff7a322c4c in rmw_dds_common::msg::typesupport_fastrtps_cpp::cdr_deserialize(eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr&, rmw_dds_common::msg::ParticipantEntitiesInfo_<std::allocator<void> >&) () from /opt/ros/humble/lib/librmw_dds_common__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so
#12 0x0000ffff7eee3f18 in ?? () from /opt/ros/humble/lib/librmw_fastrtps_cpp.so
#13 0x0000ffff7ee89f10 in rmw_fastrtps_shared_cpp::TypeSupport::deserialize(eprosima::fastrtps::rtps::SerializedPayload_t*, void*) ()
   from /opt/ros/humble/lib/librmw_fastrtps_shared_cpp.so
#14 0x0000ffff7ec9e524 in ?? () from /opt/ros/humble/lib/libfastrtps.so.2.6
#15 0x0000ffff7e993944 in eprosima::fastdds::dds::DataReaderImpl::read_or_take(eprosima::fastdds::dds::LoanableCollection&, eprosima::fastdds::dds::LoanableSequence<eprosima::fastdds::dds::SampleInfo, std::integral_constant<bool, true> >&, int, eprosima::fastrtps::rtps::InstanceHandle_t const&, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned short, bool, bool, bool) () from /opt/ros/humble/lib/libfastrtps.so.2.6
#16 0x0000ffff7e993aa4 in eprosima::fastdds::dds::DataReaderImpl::take(eprosima::fastdds::dds::LoanableCollection&, eprosima::fastdds::dds::LoanableSequence<eprosima::fastdds::dds::SampleInfo, std::integral_constant<bool, true> >&, int, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned short) ()
   from /opt/ros/humble/lib/libfastrtps.so.2.6
#17 0x0000ffff7ee82468 in rmw_fastrtps_shared_cpp::_take(char const*, rmw_subscription_s const*, void*, bool*, rmw_message_info_s*, rmw_subscription_allocation_s*) () from /opt/ros/humble/lib/librmw_fastrtps_shared_cpp.so
#18 0x0000ffff7ee72820 in ?? () from /opt/ros/humble/lib/librmw_fastrtps_shared_cpp.so
#19 0x0000ffff815e31fc in ?? () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#20 0x0000ffff82bad5c8 in start_thread (arg=0x0) at ./nptl/pthread_create.c:442
#21 0x0000ffff82c15d9c in thread_start () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/clone.S:79
```

It seems that it died because of failing to allocate during deserialize something, but I can't understand how could it happen.

In most cases, they only provide some error messages at the terminal or not, and are simply killed, like this:
[image]

I would like to know if this situation (consuming a large amount of resources during startup) is normal, and what methods are available to keep them running on my device stably.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try launching each individually or with a delay to allow each to start fully before the next.  Launching your code separately after all community packages are launched will give you insight into the behavior of your code.